# Highlight specific table cell of the row that was hovered

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, class, events

I have a table and it looks something like this:

```
| Company              | Contact         | Country  |
|---|---|---|
| Alfreds Futterkiste  | Maria Anders    | Germany  | 
| Centro Moctezuma     | Francisco Chang | Mexico   |
```

I want to be able to highlight a row (e.g. `Centro Moctezuma`) and *only* have the company name in the first column be highlighted. So when highlighting Row 2, the name `Centro Moctezuma` should be highlighted but not the name `Alfreds Futterkiste.`

I have some code that highlights all of the names in the first column when hovering over any of the rows, which isn't what I want. How can I reformat my code so that only the company name of the hovered row is highlighted?

Here's a fiddle that shows the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/hdo236vm/

---

#### HTML snippet:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td class="name">Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td class="name">Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td class="name">Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td class="name">Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td class="name">Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td class="name">Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

#### JS snippet:

```
function nameHighlight() {
    $(".row").mouseover(function () {
        $(".name").addClass("name__highlight")
    })
    $(".row").mouseleave(function () {
        $(".name").removeClass("name__highlight")
    })
}

nameHighlight();
```

#### CSS:

```
.name__highlight {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you simply use `:hover`?

Comment: Hey @sandrooco, I want to hover over anywhere in the row and have the company name be highlighted. If I do `name:hover` then I'll have to move my mouse over the name only.

Comment: You can do this with pure CSS like this: `tr.row:hover .name {
    color: red;
}`. But don't forget to remove your JS code before.

Comment: @Konrud wow, that was much simpler than I expected. If you make it an answer then I'll accept it.

Comment: @Bodrov, just did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with pure CSS like this:

```css
tr.row:hover .name {
 color: red;
}
```

Note: Don't forget to remove your JS code before you apply this CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Your code adds the .name__highlight class to all elements with the .name class. You need to search through the element you're hovering over and find the .name element within it. Like this:

```
function nameHighlight() {
    $(".row").mouseover(function () {
        $(this).find(".name").addClass("name__highlight")
    })
    $(".row").mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).find(".name").removeClass("name__highlight")
    })
}

nameHighlight();
```

Comment: You should always prefer the pure CSS solution over JS. See @Konrud's answer.

Comment: True, but this solution generalises to manipulations that can't be done in pure CSS, and explains the specifics of why the original code failed to work. I agree that the other answer should be the preferred solution, but mine also adds value.

Comment: As comment yes, not as solution though.

Comment: Not according to [the guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).